# TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined at

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting the following errors on my website when I load it on an online server.
I using express 3.x, the first url don´t has probems, but i do login the error is

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined at**

**My code is:**

```
    server.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
    server.set('view engine', 'html');
    server.set('views', './app/views');

    server.configure(function() {
        server.use(express.logger());
        server.use(express.cookieParser());
        server.use(express.bodyParser());

        server.use(express.session({
            secret: "lolcatz",
            store: new RedisStore({})
        }));
    });

    server.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.render('home');
    });

    server.get('/app', function (req, res) {
        res.render('app', { 
            user: req.session.user
        });
    });

    server.post('/log-in', function (req, res) {
        req.session.user = req.body.username;
        res.redirect('/app');
    });

    server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: My guess is that your server variable is not defined, or not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Please state software version your issue is occurring.sometimes version is the matter and I guess this time as well.

first of all, the error is happening all because of `req.session.user = req.body.username;`

which means you do not have properly set

`server.use(express.session({
  secret: "lolcatz",
  store: new RedisStore({})
}));`

Though above code should work.So I assume you are using express 4.0 and keep using `server.configure` function. Since app.configure in express version 3.x was removed in express version 4.0,The code above would not work in express 4.0

so simply remove the function and make it something like...

```
server.use(express.logger());
server.use(express.cookieParser());
server.use(express.bodyParser());

server.use(express.session({
    secret: "lolcatz",
    store: new RedisStore({})
}));

server.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.render('home');
```